# On Macrons and Vowels

Tags: orthography, lingua-latina-per-se-illustrata

Reading LLPSI, I made a list of the proper nouns with macrons in the first lesson of the first chapter:

### CAPITVLVM PRĪMVM

- Rōma
- Eurōpa
- Germānia
- Hispānia
- Āfrica
- Nīlus
- Rhēnus
- Dānuvius

---

We encounter with **Italia** and **Eurōpa**. But why Europa has a macron but Italia does not? Or why is **Dānuvius** but not **Tiberis**? I know some people recommend to just skip macrons for easyness but if I am going to learn Latin, I want to learn it properly since I'm a complete beginner.

Comment: *Tiberis* just doesn't have any long vowels in it. No idea why they didn't write *Ītalia* though, since the long *ī* seems pretty much universal. (The noun *Italus* "Italian person" has a short *i* but other forms like *Ītalis*, *Ītalicus*, etc share the long *ī*.)

Comment: Also, if you want to learn with macrons (which I wholeheartedly recommend), *prīmum* should have a long *ī* also.

Comment: @Draconis Could you expand on that a bit further? And I added that macron on *prīmum*.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you'd like expanded? Length is an intrinsic part of each vowel, and the difference between ē and e could be more prominent than between (say) e and i. *Ītalia* has one, as does *Eurōpa* and *Dānuvius*, but *Tiberis* doesn't. (Some words also have more than one, like *fīliī*.) Is this what you're asking about?

Comment: @PabloIvan You might be interested in this earlier question: [How do I use macrons?](http://latin.stackexchange.com/q/1497/79)

Comment: @Draconis If my memory serves me wll, the word *Italia* typically has no macron. The first I is long in Vergilius to fit hexameter. In prose I would write and pronounce *Italia* with short vowels.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta What do you mean, "I would **pronounce** *Italia* with short vowels*"? [emphasis mine]

Comment: @AlexB. The word *Italia* (or a variant of it) has only short vowels, and I would reflect this in pronunciation. I'd pronounce all four vowels short, the stressed one only slightly longer (as is natural with stress). The pronunciation would be the same as in Finnish, apart from the location of stress. (I'm slightly confused about what exactly confuses you, so I may or may not have answered your question.)

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Making an effort to pronounce short and long vowels distinctly in Latin - this surprised me a lot.

Comment: @AlexB. Oh! I had assumed everyone would do that all the time... Many Finns pronounce every single vowel with the correct length, but our native language must help with this distinction.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta In my experience Americans try, but don't always succeed, especially on *ā* versus *a* (since English has rough equivalents to all the others). It's just the quality difference at best though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Latin vowels can be short or long, and a macron is a sign that a vowel is long. *Rōma* has a macron over the O because the O in that word happens to be a long vowel. None of the vowels in *Tiberis* have a macron because all three vowels happen to be short. There's no particular reason why a given vowel is long or short, other than the history of the specific word: it's just part of the word, and has to be memorized separately for each word. (A word can have more than one macron in it, by the way, since any vowel can be long or short; all your examples have exactly one, but that's just a coincidence.)

Comment: what about Italia?

Comment: @AlexB., I meant that the OP's examples of words containing macrons all contain exactly one.

Answer (score 5):

I just want to add one thing to the stuff that others have noted. The reason why *Italia* does not have a macron is that this word did not normally have a long vowel. It is *scanned* as if it were *ītalia* in verse (and therefore tends to be listed as *ītalia* in resources that derive quantity exclusively from versification), but this is a metrical convenience to allow the word to be fitted into verse. Otherwise, you'd be stuck with having three light syllables in sequence, which would make it impossible to use in hexameters. Poets could do weird things to words to get them to fit into hexameters, especially with proper names because unlike with common nouns there's often no other suitable word for the thing you're referring to (though it also happens when you really want to use an important common noun like *imperator* which early poets manage to shoehorn in as *indŭpĕrātor*.) Note that the same problem does not occur with the related noun *Italus* because the word's shape makes it much more tractable in hexameters, and so the i is never lengthened in *that* word in verse.

That the reading *ītalia* is a matter of verse-license has been documented for some time in secondary literature, because it is explicitly attested by ancient sources discussing pronunciation.

*praeterea quae fiunt spatio, sive cum syllaba correpta producitur, ut **Italiam fato profugus**, seu longa corripitur, ut **unius ob noxam et furias**, extra carmen non deprehendas; sed nec in carmine vitia dicenda sunt.*

And Consentius who also makes it explicitly clear that he's talking about the length of the i in "Italiam":

*Ectasis est cum correpta syllaba poeta sic auctoritate sua utitur, tamquam sit temporis longioris, ut est **Italiam fato profugus** et **conubia nostra reppulit**, cum i et u aperte breues sint*

Comment: Welcome to the site and thanks for the answer! I look forward to reading more from you here.

Answer (score 2):

## Long sounds (vowels and consonants)

> […] a Roman wishing to differentiate vowels in his own language and having Aristophanes’ system as a model before him would surely have borrowed for his purpose the signs for long and short vowels, that is to say, the macron and breve, which, so far as we know, always had forms (¯ and ˘) that they have retained to the present day.
> ― Revilo P. Oliver (‘Apex and Sicilicus’, *The American Journal of Philology*, 87:2, pp. 129–170). P. 143.

### Macron

One of the best aspects of Ørberg’s work, is how it differentiates vowel length throughout. As explained by @TKR, a macron (ɔ: the dash – ◌̄ – on top of the vowel) denotes a long vowel. The Romans didn’t consistently use their version of macrons, but we have numerous inscriptions demonstrating how it was used, perhaps best known of this the *Rēs gestae dīvī Augustī*. In fact, they used two symbols for demonstrating a doubling of the phoneme (that is: the sound which the letter represents): an *apex* (plural *apicēs*) and a *sīcīlicus* (plural *sīcīlicī*). Oliver writes:

> The handbooks of epigraphy all assure us that two distinct diacritical marks are found in Roman inscriptions: a phonetic sign, the *apex*, shaped like an acute accent (´), which was placed above a vowel-letter to show that the vowel was long and not short; and an orthographic sign, the *sicilicus*, shaped like a small inverted c or a modern comma (’), which was placed above a consonant to show that the consonant should be doubled (e.g., s̓ = ss).
> ― Oliver 1966: 129.

We also see the apex in the shape of a diagonal bar. Generally, both this symbol and the apex would begin where the letter ended, and extend somewhat over the next one (*op. cit.* 144).

Now, Quintilian claims that it is completely useless to mark long vowels where there is no doubt whether it should or should be a long vowel – in other words: Whenever you encounter a word which is differentiated only by vowel length, such as *malus* (evil, bad) vs. *mālus* (apple), you would add the macron (or for the Romans: the *apex*). The numerous inscriptions, however, clearly show that *only* marking long vowels when needed, was not the common practice.

> The use of the apex in inscriptions makes it obvious that, from the very first, the function of the apex was to show the correct pronunciation of words that, presumably, were sometimes mispronounced in current speech.
> ― *Op. cit.* 135.

### *I longa* – long I

In addition to this, a long *i* was not shown with a symbol, but with the so-called *I longa*, ɔ: ‘long I’. In the below example, you can see numerous very thin, delicate lines above many of the vowels (*apicēs*), and several examples of the I longa:

[image: Augusto sacra inscription, demonstrating apicēs and I longa]

### *Sīcīlicus* – ‘the small sickle’

> There are, however, enough examples to support the definition given in our handbooks by showing that the mark was indeed used to indicate double consonants […]. [–––] Inscriptions of the late Republic and early Augustan period do show SABEL̓IO for Sabellio, OS̓A for ossa, MVM̓IAES as the ‘archaic’ genitive of Mummia, and possibly VET̓IVS for Vetius.
> ― *Op. cit.*: 145.

It is also worth noting that in mediaeval manuscripts, you very often will find a macron over consonants to show doubling or to show a missing nasal: *damnū* = *damnum*; gram̄aticus = grammaticus.

## Short vowels

It is common for many dictionaries, such as the standard Lewis & Short dictionary (just google ‘Perseus Lewis and Short’) where you will find another symbol: the breve (◌̆), ɔ: the short vowel symbol. However, to continue from my opening quote:

> But although a sign for a short vowel would have been decidedly useful in Latin for purposes of differentiation (so long as *all* long vowels were not marked), there is no indication that such a sign was ever used or even suggested.
> ― *Op. cit.*: 143.

That doesn’t mean we can’t find good use for it today. I find it very useful to use this symbol when I do my readings in LLPSI or other books, when memorising words which I tend to make mistakes with regards to vowel length. For example, is ‘river’ in Latin *fluvius* or *flūvius*? The latter is incorrect, so when practicing, I will write *flŭvius* to assure I remember the correct vowel length.

Answer (score 1):

Ī agrēe that learning the language with macrons is important. The mēaning often chānges depending on whether the vowel is short or long.

In English wē have short and long vowels as well.

It would benefit a foreigner tō knōw where the long vowels are.

For instance:
bōw vs bow

> bōw and arrow VS bow down

prīmer vs primer ("primmer")

> prīmer, first cōat of pāint
>   VS primer, a beginning lesson.

As you can sēe, vowel length is not always predictable in English. The sāme is the cāse in Latin.

māne = early (Crās māne = early in the morning)
manē = wait! (Manē, Marce! = Wait, Marcus! )

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the site. It is only incidental to your answer, but are you sure about the translation of _cras mane_? I would have guessed it means “tomorrow morning.”

Comment: The English distinction that's taught in school as "short vowels vs. long vowels" is really one of vowels vs. diphthongs, which is rather different from the Latin situation. (The two *bow* words, by the way, are something else again -- the difference there is between two diphthongs.)