# How to know long and short vowels if it is not marked?

Tags: pronunciation, vowel-quantity

Latin has vowels which are long and short. The long ones are marked by a dash on the top of the letter. How do I know how to pronounce the letters if the long and short vowels are not marked in a text?

Comment: Welcome to the site! The dash is called a macron. Does [this old question and its answer](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/1497/79) answer your question? If yes, we can link your question to it (as a duplicate) and make the answer easier to find. If no, can you elaborate on what is missing?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Although the other question begs the question from the point of writing, I asked it from the point of pronouncing. But it answered my question. As I understand, I have to learn it word by word. If my understanding of the answer is right, let this be marked as a duplicate.

Comment: I marked this question as duplicate. It is indeed the case that you have to learn it word by word and ending by ending. You will get better at guessing as you progress, but there are very few hard rules.

Comment: @Joonas To be fair to the OP, the title of the duplicate question is quite different from what's being asked here, even though the answer to the one ends up covering the same material.

Comment: @brianpck I agree! I'm not blaming Mainul Islam for not finding it. I happened to remember it, but that was just lucky. But that's what duplicates are good for: Now that two different titles lead to the same knowledge, it has become easier to find. Frankly, I think this one has a more descriptive title, and in any case this is a good question and earned my vote.